# Wordpress themes button in wp-admin wont work and shows me error "This site doesn't work"

Tags: wordpress, themes

recently I'm trying to learn WordPress and deployed my first website locally. I created a theme and used it for the website, but now if I click on "Design" and "themes" the theme site wont work anymore:
[button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o1wG.png)
[themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXaBm.png)

Has anyone an idea what the problem could be suddenly? The site itself works normally, but in the inde.php is the message "Silence is golden"
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check your error logs to find the bug:  https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/